# Making a TIME SERIES graph THAT SCROLLS WITH THE DATA in R

Tags: r, scroll, time-series, rstudio

I need to do exactly the graph that has been made on this page (the second one)
http://www.animatedgraphs.co.uk/line.html

Here is my actual code :

```
timemax<-151737 # number of frames (and observations - so no interpolation needed)
setwd("C:/Users/victo/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/")
vis<-100 # how many time points are on the screen at one time
gdata<-data.frame('Temps'= data$time,'RH_Xacc'= data$RH_Xacc)

gname<-paste("g",1:timemax,".tif", sep="") # holds the names of the picture files
right<-(((1:timemax)<=vis)*100)+(((1:timemax)>vis)*1:timemax) # rightmost time on screen
left<- right-vis+2 # leftmost time on screen
leftlab<-200*ceiling((left-1)/200) # leftmost x label
rightlab<-200*floor(right/200) # rightmost x label

# draw graphs
for (i in 1:timemax) {
tiff(gname[i],width=480)
plot(gdata$Temps[right[i]:left[i]],gdata$RH_Xacc[right[i]:left[i]],col="red",type="l",ylim=c(-100,200),xlim=c(right[i],left[i]),xaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="time")
axis(1,at=seq(from=rightlab[i],to=leftlab[i],by=12))
lines(gdata$Temps[right[i]:i],gdata$RH_Xacc[right[i]:i])
dev.off(dev.cur())
}

 # call FFMPEG and make the video
 shell("C:/Users/victo/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -codecs -i g%d.tif -b:v 2048k gdata.mpg",mustWork=FALSE)
```

My code seems to work until the shell function. I don't get an error. The code just never stops running. I am not able to get the video with all the data. Can someone tell me where is the problem ? How can I get the video or if there is an other to get the same result ? I've tried the library gganimate but i didn't succeed either... I am doing this in Rstudio and using sweave.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the first thing you should do is probably run the command : 
`C:/Users/victo/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -codecs -i g%d.tif -b:v 2048k gdata.mpg` directly and not with a calling `shell` from RStudio. You would have a more verbose output.

**Original post**

Do you have any CPU performance profiling tool ? I suspect that the `shell` command might take a lot of time to run on your computer since in your example : `timemax<-151737` whereas the example has a shorter timemax `timemax<-1000`

Try your program with a low value of `timemax (=1000)` and time the execution of the code. I guess you could extrapolate the total time needed to execute multiplying by 150 (I am not an expert of `ffmpeg`, it might actually be longer)